# Jhipster aws subgenerator throws Invalid DB engine on fresh install

Tags: amazon-web-services, generator, jhipster

I try to use jhipster was  in a fresh install of hipster 7.0.1
With was account with following permission:

- AmazonRDSFullAccess
- ElasticLoadBalancingFullAccess
- AdministratorAccess
- AmazonECS_FullAccess
- IAMFullAccess

But when the generator tries to create the postrgess RDS i got the Invalid DB engine error.

```
Create S3 bucket
Bucket invec already exists

Upload WAR to S3
War uploaded successful

Create database
/home/outis/dev/jhipster/invec/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

Error: Invalid DB engine
    at module.exports.error (/home/outis/dev/jhipster/invec/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:1787:11)
    at /home/outis/dev/jhipster/invec/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/aws/index.js:192:18
    at /home/outis/dev/jhipster/invec/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/aws/lib/rds.js:56:19
    at Response.<anonymous> (/home/outis/dev/jhipster/invec/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/aws/lib/rds.js:145:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/outis/dev/jhipster/invec/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:369:18)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/outis/dev/jhipster/invec/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/home/outis/dev/jhipster/invec/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/home/outis/dev/jhipster/invec/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/home/outis/dev/jhipster/invec/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/outis/dev/jhipster/invec/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /home/outis/dev/jhipster/invec/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/outis/dev/jhipster/invec/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/outis/dev/jhipster/invec/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/outis/dev/jhipster/invec/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
    at Request.emit (/home/outis/dev/jhipster/invec/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/home/outis/dev/jhipster/invec/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14) {
  code: 'Error',
  time: 2021-05-28T22:46:56.333Z
```

I will appreciate any information to fix this.

Comment: I opened a github issue https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/15151

Answer (score 1):

It's a regression bug introduced in 7.0.1 that changed the `dbEngine` value from "postgres" to "postgresql". The right value is "postgres" as [documented in AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/create-db-instance.html#options)

Until the 7.1.0 version is released, you can patch the sub generator by yourself by editing `node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/aws/index.js` in your project and modify `checkDatabase()` function this way:

```js
      checkDatabase() {
        const prodDatabaseType = this.config.get(PROD_DATABASE_TYPE);

        switch (prodDatabaseType.toLowerCase()) {
          case MARIADB:
            this.dbEngine = MARIADB;
            break;
          case MYSQL:
            this.dbEngine = MYSQL;
            break;
          case POSTGRESQL:
            this.dbEngine = 'postgres';
            break;
          default:
            this.error('Sorry deployment for this database is not possible');
        }
      },
```